# if(self = [super init]) - LLVM warning! How are you dealing with it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, llvm, xcode4

Prior to Xcode 4 with LLVM this passed the compiler unnoticed. Assignment within the conditional is perfectly intentional and a Cocoa idiom.

Xcode 4 with LLVM compiler selected never fails to complain, and not just at compile time, as soon as you type it the yellow warning icon appears. Turning off warnings as errors and just ignoring the warning doesn't seem like a good idea. Moving the assignment out of the parentheses wastes space. Having to turn off this warning with a pragma for every new project will become tedious.

How are you dealing with it? What's the new idiom going to be?

Comment: When formatting code, "wasting space" is not necessarily really a waste.  Indenting lines to reflect program structure "wastes space" but you don't not do it do you?

Comment: Wasting space relative to the idiom of assign/evaluate for self only. I care a lot about how dense the code looks and don't mind extra lines at all when it makes things clearer.

Comment: Love the double negative JeremyP.

Comment: I just noticed that, as of Xcode 5.1.1 (at least), you can now get away with using only one pair of parentheses and still the warning won't show up. I wonder what's going on behind the scenes...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually a very old warning, it was just off by default with GCC and with Clang 1.6. Xcode should actually give you a suggestion for how to fix it - namely, double the parentheses.

```
if ((self = [super init])) { ... }
```

The extra pair of parens tells the compiler that you really did intend to make an assignment in the conditional.

Comment: So it does - I just assumed I knew what it was complaining about so I did not read the tooltip.

Answer (score 10):

If you create an init method from the newer Xcode text macros, you'll noticed that the new blessed way to do init is:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        <#initializations#>
    }
    return self;
}
```

This avoids the warning.  Though personally in my own code if I come across this I've simply been applying the method Kevin showed.

Something good to know!

Comment: Not exactly sure you can call this a new "blessed way". Apple has always been inconsistent about coding styles.

Comment: I didn't say the previous styles were not once also blessed... In computing, no blessing is forever.  So perhaps it's more of a "charm".

Comment: Both Kevin's and Kendall's answers are valid.  The difference between them is that Kendall's checks to see if the initialization of the superclass worked. Aaron Hillegass explains in his book that some initializers will return nil if the initialization of the superclass fails. I'm under the impression that such a case would be pathological (a runtime failure) which is why there don't appear to be any examples   of retrying the initialization in the event of a nil return. I'm out of my depth here, though, and only speculating on that bit.  I'd love to see an authoritative in depth explanation.

Comment: There is no functional difference between my answer and Kevins, they both check to see if the superclass was created - his just wraps the assignment in the if, a shorthand version of the code I presented.  The main thing is that LLDB (rightfully) has warnings around assignment in an if clause, so we just have two ways to work around the warning, both valid...

Answer (score 4):

Just use two pairs of parentheses to make it clear to the compiler that you're assigning on purpose:

```
if ((self = [super init]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Bring up the project navigator and choose your project. In the main window that appears, choose "All". Under the section "LLVM compiler 2.0 - Warnings", choose "Other Warning Flags". Add the flag "Wno-idiomatic-parentheses" for both "Debug" and "Release." Now clean and recompile.[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a few others have suggested you should add an extra set of parenthesis.

I'm far from a regular expression guru so feel free to clean this up but this find and replace in Xcode fixed about 95% of my instances:

```
Replace: if\s*\({1}\s*self\s*={1}(.*)\){1}
With:    if ((self =\1))
```

Be careful because this will also find if (self == ...), so use preview and uncheck those or fix my regex :)

And start using self = ...;  if (self), it's cleaner.