# Objective C - iPhone: using nil in comparision

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nimbus

I see some code in Nimbus look like this:

```
if (nil == someObject)
```

but I usually type:

```
if (someObject == nil)
```

Are there any differences in these statements?

Comment: Why not just test this yourself? `if (nil == someObject && someObject == nil) NSLog(@"woohoo!");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically no. The former, Nimbus, is using what is endearingly called ["Yoda Conditions"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html).

The name of the game being foolproofing here. See, the problem is that this:

```
if (someObject = nil) // SETS someObject to nil
```

is totally valid, only one character away from `== nil`, and really easy to miss. However, if you attempt to do this:

```
if (nil = someObject)
```

your compiler will freak out, preventing the issue.

Personally, I *hate* Yoda Conditionals, as I think they're hard to read. It does mean being extra careful with my code, but hey, I'm the better for it, right? It all comes down to style here, so whatever makes you more comfortable, go for.

Oh, and if you're using Xcode, this is nearly a moot point. If you check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344810/xcode-4-if-self-super-init-issue), you'll see that Xcode now warns you if you attempt to do an assignment within an `if` without extra parens. That is,

```
if (someObject = nil) // throws a warning, whereas
if ((someObject = nil)) // does not
```

making the issue much harder to miss.

Answer (score 4):

No.

(Extra blah blab blah for SO minimum post rules.  Weren't they useful?)

Answer (score 3):

They're functionally the same, it's just a coding style issue.

In the olden days, your compiler wouldn't warn you if you missed out an equals sign.

```
if (someObject = nil)
```

Probably doesn't do what you want. But if you invert them:

```
if (nil = someObject)
```

then the compiler will complain.

These days it probably doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I remember doing an assignment in an if statement several years ago. It took me THREE DAYS to track down my error.

Answer (score 1):

No. but below code is more readability.

> Left-hand side: The expression “being interrogated,” whose value is
>   more in flux.
>
> Right-hand side: The expression being compared against,
>   whose value is more constant.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference nowadays is that the second form is more readable (or maybe it's subjective and it's only me who prefer it).