# Turn Off Xcode 4's Annoying Fix-it Feature

Tags: xcode, if-statement, warnings

I wonder if there is a way to stop Xcode 4 warning me about using the assignment operator inside, for example, an if-statement and suggesting me to either place parentheses around the assignment or use the equality comparison operator. There is no need to warn me about these kind of things, I know what I'm doing!

So has anyone figured out how to do this? Thanks if you can tell me.

Comment: Warning about that kind of thing is a pretty standard feature in good compilers. I, for one, am glad it is there, that is far too common of a typo that generates headaches when debugging

Answer (score 1):

That might depends on the compiler you use, but you can tune compilation warnings using the Build Setting "Other Warning Flags".

Adding `-Wno-idiomatic-parentheses` is supposed to suppress this particular warning.

Look at [this very similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940366/ifself-super-init-llvm-warning-how-are-you-dealing-with-it)

An see [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/compilercodewarnings.html) Apple documentations for more details.

And avoid using LLVM2.0, it is bugged.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Vincent! Another way to silence this warning is by setting "Missing Braces and Parenthesis" to "No" under "LLVM compiler 2.0 - Warnings" in your project's build settings.