# Xcode 4 disable "fix-it" popup

Tags: xcode4, popup

I'm fine with Xcode 4 telling me that I have an error.  But that pop-up pretty much always has the wrong solution.  Is there any way I can get rid of it permanently?

Comment: That's interesting because in my case the fix-it solution is always correct.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, it looks like you may need to disable the various types of warnings one by one. A list is found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

To change them:

Bring up the project navigator and choose your project. In the main window that appears, choose "All". Under the section "LLVM compiler 2.0 - Warnings", choose "Other Warning Flags". Add the flag "Wno-idiomatic-parentheses" for both "Debug" and "Release." Now clean and recompile ( from [if(self = [super init]) - LLVM warning! How are you dealing with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940366/ifself-super-init-llvm-warning-how-are-you-dealing-with-it))

I noted in the apple dev link that the following option should inhibit all warnings:

```
-w Inhibit all warning messages.
```

Comment: Did you intend to put this answer on a different question?