# In Objective-C, is there a shorter way to write the init method?

Tags: objective-c

Seems like whenever we need to initialize an object, we need to immediately write

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // initialize values here
    }
    return self;
}
```

is there a shorter way to do it?  Maybe even by a macro?

Comment: it is very short & simple already.

Comment: Why don't you add a code snippet in Xcode itself? Check [here](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/05/dev-juice-how-do-i-autocomplete-in-xcode-4/)

Comment: coz i think in Ruby, you just type `super` and then next line you start the init code and that's it... very short...

Comment: @JeremyL: You're totally right, but Ruby's whole idiom of object creation is different. Ruby uses the class method `new`, which calls `initialize`, while Objective-C uses `alloc` and `init`. This means that, for example, you can have an `init` method that returns a different object than the one you originally allocated, or nothing if the initialization fails. You can't do that with `initialize`. So basically, the two languages are different things. This is how Objective-C works. It's a bit wordy, but you can't make it Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get away with one line fewer, but this isn't recommended practice anymore:

```
- (id) init {

    if((self = [super init])){
        // initialize ivars
    }
    return self;
}
```

Boilerplate is boilerplate, unfortunately, and each of the things that initializers do: assign `self` to the result of `[super init]` (or the superclass's designated initializer), check `self` is not `nil`, initialize ivars, and return `self` (whether `nil` or a valid object) are all necessary.

To spare yourself some typing, you can make a code snippet in Xcode.

Comment: +1 for the code snippet. If you are going to be lazy don't punish other developers.

Comment: do you know why it is not recommended any more? coz it is perfectly fine usage (at least back in the old days)... will it be... another developer mis-read it as `if (self == [super init])` or even "edit it to make it correct"... and change the `=` to `==`

Comment: @Jeremy: I guess "recommended practice" may be too strong a phrasing. Perhaps I should have said "no longer the fashion". http://stackoverflow.com/q/4940366/ There's a few (I can think of three off the top of my head) of different, equally correct, ways of writing initializers, which have variously been "the way it's done" over the years of Cocoa's existence (and probably NeXT before that).

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to perform all these operations in your designated initializer, so there's no easy shortcut.

Theoretically, you can go a macro route, but the macro is not going to be pretty, and it will be counterintuitive to the readers of your code.

```
#define BEGIN_INIT self=[super init];if(self){
#define END_INIT }return self

-(id) init {
    BEGIN_INIT;
    // initialize values here
    END_INIT;
}
```

This code is not much shorter, and it is a lot less familiar to others. I strongly recommend agains it.

Comment: Really, don't do this. It makes the code way less readable in exchange for…uh…dropping two lines of code once a class